# Meteor user is undefined when accessing data

Tags: javascript, meteor

**EDIT: The problem has been solved. I recently changed the publish rules which caused the emails not to get published to the client.**

I have a problem: I am trying to send a notification email upon a form submit. This is the code

```
var fl = Meteor.users.find({_id:owner});
console.log(fl);

var email = fl.emails[0].address;
var html = Blaze.toHTMLWithData(Template.new_assigned_task_email);
Meteor.call('sendEmail',
      email,
      "email@email.com",
      "You have a new task offer!",
      html);
```

the variable owner is a user ID. console.log(owner) returns the correct id, console.log(fl) returns the user object. However, `calling fl.emails[0].address`gives me the "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'fl.emails[0]')" error.

is there anything that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meteor.users.find` returns [cursor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_cursor) and you need to retrieve user as js object.

Try:

```
var fl = Meteor.users.findOne({_id:owner});
// OR
var fl = Meteor.users.findOne(owner) 

console.log(fl);
```

Comment: thank you, however I am still getting the same error

Comment: paste result of  console.dir( fl ) or console.log( JSON.stringify( fl, null, 2 ) ) in form of screenshot

Comment: As mentioned above, the problem is solved. However, Meteor.users.findOne(owner) returns a much cleaner JSON object, so thank you anyway for the hint!